# html controls event handling on the server side

Tags: asp.net

I'm adding multiple divs at runtime from my Server side code.

```
mainSubjectDiv.Controls.Add(headerDiv);
```

now I want to handle the click event on the server side. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add events to controls from your code using regular .NET event syntax:

```
headerDiv.Click += new EventHandler(headerDiv_Click);

public void headerDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .................//Your code will be here
}
```